# Domain Name and server issue

Tags: domain, name

I am new in web hosting. So please help me out. My problem is as follows:

one of my friend has approached to a web hosting company to purchase one domain name and create one website for his organisation. That company did that. After that, that company has been closed due to some reason(we don't know the reason). Now neither they are reachable on phone nor responding on the mail. Now My friend wants to do some changes in that website and he told me to do that.

Right now we have following details:
1. server control panel link
2. username-Not working
3. password- also not working
4. mail ids with this domain name

These information has been provided by that company through mail which was the last reply from them.

As you all understood, we want full control for this web hosting as well as for this domain name.

So please tell us how we should proceed, what steps we should follow etc.

Any help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Gopal

Comment: Have you whois yourdomain.com to find out who the current registrar is...? If the first company went under.

Comment: Of course you want full control for this web pages as well as for the domain name. But the question is: who owns it. This is not always the person or organisation who commissioned the website. Sometimes they just end up hiring a web page and the creator is free to increase fees whenever he wants. Or to sell it to the competition.  The last is unlikely to happen because it gives the creator a very bad name, but curators have no such scruples. They task is to squeeze as much money out of a bankrupt firm as possible.

Comment: Which means you 1) Look for the paperswork and read it carefully. Sometimes it specifies what to do in such an occasion.  2) Look up who owns the domain name (via nslookup as specified below in Javano's answer

Answer (score 1):

Perform an nslookup on the domain name of the web site. Look at who owns the domain name, (which name servers are hosting those record) then contact that company (look at the SOA records for example).

Also look at who owns the IP (perform a whois search against the IP returned when performing a DNS A record query against the web site address) and contact that company also (in case it is a different company).

One of those two companies will hopefully know who owns the web server on which your friends site is running (unless is a reseller taking wholesale service, but that just means 1 extra hoop to jump through).